# How to change texture in Gera library?

Tags: javascript, gera

I'm learning Gera WebGL library, and I wonder how can I change the texture of mesh in it?

I'm creating the rotating box like that:

```
var cube = new Gera.Cube({
    geometry: {
        alpha: 1,
        beta: 1,
        gamma: 1,
        delta: 1,
        epsilon: 1,
        dzeta: 1
    },
    position: {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        z: -7
    },
    rotation: {
        x: 1,
        y: 0,
        z: 1,
        autostart: true,
        angle: 45
    },
    texture: 'imagePath.jpg'
});

scene.add( cube );
```

But what if I want to change the texture after some action/event, what should I do?

There is less information in [official spectification](http://magesi.ru/gera/specification)

The code above was taken from the index page, and some pretty sample from some [playground scene](http://magesi.ru/gera/scene)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the way, how to achieve the texture change.

You can do this with using the next code:

```
window.setTimeout( function() {
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = 'new-file-path.jpg';
    image.onload = function( event ) {
        var handledImage = event.target || event.srcElement;
        cube.texture.image = handledImage;
    };
}, 1000 );
```

The texture will be updated in 1 second.

Also, Gera right now doesn't provide CORS origin requests, so be careful with fetching image data, if you will try to fetch image from remote server it won't be updated, you should put your textures in localhost.